# Custom front end for web server authentication (alternative to Apache)

Tags: apache, docker, authentication, ldap, webserver

I'm running an Apache web server with a basic authentication, like as follows:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication required"
AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

Actually the Authentication/Authorization configuration is a little more complex because I'm querying an LDAP server.
I would like to be able to use a custom web page instead of the traditional pop-up that comes with the 401 that Apache sends to the web browser.
Two questions:

- Is Apache capable of doing so? (AFAIK, no);
- Which alternative product would be a good option given that I'm running everything inside Docker containers and it has to be able to do LDAP Authentication/Authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom 401 error page as described in [Apache documentation here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html).

But you should consider using your structure in `Location` (or some other) structure

```
ErrorDocument 401 /error/error401.html
<Location />
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication required"
AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this ErrorDocument directive is effective after the Authentication takes place, while I need a way to customize the web page where the user inserts its credentials.

Comment: @espogian, I am not sure web server can do this. You will need application server and full power authentication app.